# Floating Point system with base 10

Tags: numerical-methods

It is a long time ago I used floating points, so I struggle with the following question and hope that you can help me out.

I need to list all numbers that can be represented exactly in a normalised floating- point number system with base 10, two digits in the fraction, and an exponent $0 ≤ e ≤ 2$. How many are there in total (including zero)? What is the machine epsilon?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia provides [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Range_of_floating-point_numbers) to obtain the number of *normalized floating-point* numbers in a system:

$$2\cdot(B − 1)\cdot(B^{P − 1})\cdot(e_{max} − e_{min} + 1) + 1,$$
 where $B$ is the base, $P$ is the precision, $e_{max}$ is the maximum exponent, and $e_{min}$ is the minimum exponent.
See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104174/how-to-find-the-number-of-normalised-floating-point-numbers-in-a-system) to see why the formula holds.

Substituting the required values gives that the number of numbers that can be represented in your *normalized floating-point number system* is 541.

The machine epsilon gives an upper bound on the relative error caused by rounding in floating-point arithmetic. It can be approximated by the formula $\dfrac{b^{p-1}}{2}$ or $b^{p-1}$, where $b$ is the base and $p$ is the precision. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#How_to_determine_machine_epsilon) for more details and for an algorithmic approach, you mind find [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511349/how-to-calculate-machine-epsilon-in-matlab) useful.

Comment: Thank you, so there are 541 numbers, that is from 0 to 540. How do I find the machine epsilon?

Comment: @KingDingeling I updated my post. Hope it helps.

Comment: awesome, thank you!